# How to get Trig Form from Root

Tags: simplifying-expressions, trigonometry

```
Simplify`TrigToRoot[Cos[Pi/9]]
```

gives out

> `Root[-1 - 6 #1 + 8 #1^3 &, 3]`

But when I want to do the inverse operation:

```
(InverseFunction@Simplify`TrigToRoot)@Root[-1 - 6 #1 + 8 #1^3 &, 3]
```

It doesn't work.

But following code did.

```
Root[-1 - 6 #1 + 8 #1^3 &, 3] // ToRadicals // ComplexExpand
```

> The usage of `InverseFunction` comes from here:
>
> `(InverseFunction@Prime)@7` gives 4, `Prime@4` returns 7

My question is , why can't it work and how to make it work?

Comment: Presumably `InverseFunction` has no built-in knowledge of `Simplify\`TrigToRoot`. It was not designed to do such things.